# ADT 22.3 (android 4.4) - getting error "After scene creation, #init() must be called"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, gui-designer, android-4.4-kitkat

After installing the new ADT (22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) which supports Android 4.4 (KitKat), I keep getting the error as shown here:

[image]

> An internal error has occurred

In the list of errors, I see multiple items of "RenderPreview", and when I click on any of them, I see:

> An internal error has occurred. After scene creation, #init() must be
>   called

When testing the new ADT on another computer, I can't see this error appearing there. This is very weird.

Why do I get those errors, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problems.

Comment: @DixieFlatline that's good. it means I didn't do anything wrong (this time :)  )

Comment: Exactly the same problem, I just also opened a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757912/eclipse-error-renderpreview) myself. Didn't see your question before.

Comment: I also using Scene class in my project(for starting transtion) but min API version 19 but I want to support under 19 how can I change this ?

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu I don't know about Scene class, but in order to support lower APIs, you need to set "minSdkVersion" in the manifest. the "targetSdkVersion" should be set to the max available (which is 21 currently) . I suggest reading the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: yeah I know this but function doesnt working under 19 API.

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu Which function is it that you are trying to use? there are many classes/functions that can overcome this inside the support library and third party libraries. If there isn't, you can always perform a check: "if(VERSION.SDK_INT>=VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)..." .

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've created a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61818&thanks=61818&ts=1383675338). Until it gets fixed, set the API version in the UI preview to something lower than 19. The error only shows up for version 19.

Comment: what's weird is that on some computers it doesn't occur.

Comment: FYI: the bug status got set to "fixed", so i guess it will be part of the next ADT update.

Comment: ah, thank you for your answer. Today, got this error after update into kitkat... weird

Comment: seems that this bug was fixed. i've updated the SDK (to 22.3? i'm not sure) and now it works fine.

Comment: Yes, confirmed. The latest SDK update fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same experience, but one downgrade to Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) is for me now only the successful temporary solution.

Comment: Sadly, the same computer also has another issue (with custom views) on the UI designer, no matter which ADT it has. I've reported about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119907/no-preview-of-custom-views-on-ui-designer-in-eclipse

Answer (score 6):

Just scroll down from API 19 to API 18, The Android Image in the Graphical Layout.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution until Google fixes it:

Workaround: Switch to Android-18 in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right).

Reference: Stack Overflow question *[How to fix Eclipse ADT Plugin 22.3 / SDK Tools 22.3 with broken properties window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745852/how-to-fix-eclipse-adt-plugin-22-3-sdk-tools-22-3-with-broken-properties-windo/19844123#19844123)*

Answer (score 1):

After installing the new ADT (22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) which supports Android 4.4 (kitkat), I got the same error.

Then set the API version in the UI preview to something lower than 19. The error only shows up for version 19.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it is a new bug. May be we need to wait for Google to update it.