# Eclipse error alert on opening Graphics Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.4-kitkat

Whenever I open Graphics Layout of xml file Eclipse pops up an error message as shown below. I started having this problem after I installed SDK for android 4.4 kitkat and updated SDK tools.

[image]

I tried solutions found on other SO questions but they did not solve my issue. Any idea to solve this?

**EDIT :**
Error detail "An internal error has occurred.
After scene creation, #init() must be called".

Comment: Update your ADT also..

Comment: @amalBit Do you mean Help->Check for updates? I have tried that already.

Comment: Can you give more description about the error, even I got rendering issues. When I changed the layout target to API 19 it got resolved.

Comment: @amalBit I added error detail in question.

Comment: Hey, see this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19751149/2219600

Comment: @amalBit I just found it and few others. You can answer if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a bug reported [here.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61818&thanks=61818&ts=1383675338)

One current solution is to downgrade your build to 4.3 until that reported bug is resolved.

*Workaround:

         switch to Android-18 in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right).*

Answer (score 0):

After installing the new ADT (22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) which supports Android 4.4 (kitkat), I got the same error.

Then Set the API version in the UI preview to something lower than 19. The error only shows up for version 19.enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this bug still trouble you, A workround is never preview layouts on multiple device at same time, on preview menu, choose manual preview, it's works fine on API 19.