# Multiple Layouts Previews for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey guys I am trying to get multiple layouts previews for a single app in the Graphical view in eclipse for android. like how our layour would look on different screen sizes.

here is how it looks

[image]

Hope someone will help me out with this...

Also I have searched here before posting but didnt get it so dont down rate please.

Thanks

Comment: I have attached the image I can see it above...BTW here is the link : http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJVXh.jpg

Comment: You already got preview of multiple screens, what do you want other than this?

Comment: @PareshMayani he asked about layouts, not previews...

Comment: @androiddeveloper ohh.....I got it wrong. He might want to create different layouts (like land, large-land) for particular layout!!

Comment: @PareshMayani but that has nothing to do with the UI designer. he needs to either set the values in different folders (with different qualifiers) or create multiple layout files , each in a different folder (with different qualifiers)

Comment: It is still not quite clear to me exactly what you are after ? I am not sure if Android developer has it correct.

Comment: I am with Ryan, @AndroidHero could you explain a little more exactly *what* the question/issue is?

Comment: Yeah sure...I have taken this screen from a video uploaded on YT. So the thing is like here in eclipse the person has done something so he is able to get the previews of how the layout would look on each screensize... So I would like to get to implement something similar...as in the above image...Hope I'm clear now...

Comment: @PareshMayani - this I have taken from some video I want to implement the same now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image below, click where the arrow is pointing to and select "Preview All Screen Sizes"

[image]

I guess that's a little hard to see but its the little page icon right next to "Pallete" on the top-left. Its the layout configuration drop-down.

Comment: I'm in office so would try this ASAP I reach home...And will mark this answer if I would be able to get what I am looking for...Thanks

Comment: No problem, this is what you are looking for. In the future, try to be a little more explicit with your questions. For example, until you stated in the comment that you got this screenshot from somewhere else, everyone thought that it was your own which made it quite confusing.

Comment: Hehe yeah I can understand that...Sorry for that would keep that in mind...Actually posting on SOF after a long time...If you think my question was helpful then please rate it...Thanks for your help buddy

Comment: I tried and I think its what I need. But I am getting this error can you have a look at this please?
http://tinypic.com/r/1z2m4uh/5

Comment: @ShivamChopra this error looks like what i got on another computer, as i've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751149/adt-22-3-android-4-4-getting-error-after-scene-creation-init-must-be-ca . you can either set the API on the UI designer to be lower, or try to uninstall everything related to the ADT&SDK and try to re-install it all over again.

Comment: Till now I have just downloaded sdk 4.3 and 4.4 ... ANd reinstalling everything would be tiresome because the internet speed is very slow here...

Answer (score 1):

you can add more previews and show all of the previews, as shown on the google IO video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ

it's shown on 20:30