# Showing multiple screen types simultaneously in ADT graphical editor?

Tags: android, adt, graphical-layout-editor

I seem to remember seeing a way to use ADT's graphical layout editor to preview multiple display types (i.e., 10in tablet portrait, 4in phone landscape, etc.) simultaneously.

Is there an automated way to do this, or was it probably just someone manually creating new panes in Eclipse?  Or is there another tool that does such a presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Graphical Layout press the little arrow next to your current Phone, 
in the Pulldown menu you can check "Preview All Screens"

[image: *screenshot to be edited*]

afaik you can either use landscape or portrait but you can switch the mode with the button next to the phone

Comment: refer here for screenshot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097607/multiple-layouts-previews-for-android-in-eclipse